# How do I fix an APT that complains about missing liblber?

Tags: debian, apt, shared-library

```
# apt update
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: error while loading shared libraries: liblber-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: error while loading shared libraries: liblber-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Unterprozess https hat Fehlercode zurückgegeben (127)
E: Methode /usr/lib/apt/methods/https ist nicht korrekt gestartet.
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Unterprozess https hat Fehlercode zurückgegeben (127)
E: Methode /usr/lib/apt/methods/https ist nicht korrekt gestartet.
```

It's broken. Obviously something is missing but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The shared library file `liblber-2.4.so.2` is apparently missing or damaged, and the https module of the apt package management tool depends on it.

At least on Debian 9, this library file is in package `libldap-2.4-2_<pkg_version>_<arch>.deb`. Download that package from your distribution's package repository (e.g. manually, using a web browser, or using another system and removable media, or whatever), and install it using `dpkg -i /pathname/to/libldap-2.4-2_*.deb` as root.

Alternatively, you could change your package repository configuration to use http instead of https; the packages themselves are still cryptographically signed so they can be automatically verified by apt. Then you could install the missing package or packages.

Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory: change all `https://` URLs to `http://` versions. If some repository only offers `https` access, you may have to find another repository from a [list of Debian mirror sites](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) to replace the https-only one.

Comment: How can i switch the config to http ?

Comment: Edited my answer.